# What is the difference between the ? operator and returning Err(e)?

Tags: rust

[The ? operator for easier error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) from the Rust Edition Guide says that this line:

```rust
let mut f = File::open("username.txt")?;
```

is a shorthand for this entire match statement:

```rust
let f = File::open("username.txt");

let mut f = match f {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(e) => return Err(e),
};
```

What is the actual difference between the `?` operator and returning `Err(e)`?

Consider the code:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", foo());
}

fn foo() -> Result<(), String> {
    Err("error")?;          // (1) this is fine
    //return Err("error");  // (2) compilation error: 'mismatched types'
    
    Ok(())
}
```

If the `?` operator was just a sugar-syntax for returning appropriate `Err` from function then I would expect (1) and (2) to treated in the same way by the compiler. What is the difference we can observe in the example above?

Comment: From the duplicate: *It returns the error if not [OK], calling `Into::into` on the error value to potentially convert it to another type.* The edition guide (and the duplicate, before I edited it) omits that the error value can change type via `?`. That's how your `&str` becomes a `String`.